# Colormap diverging from black instead of white?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like a diverging colormap that has another colour than white (preferably black) as it center color. Neither matplotlib or cmocean seems to have such a colormap. Is my best option to create an own colormap, or are there existing ones?

Comment: The point of a diverging color map is to show different data points correlated with the intensity of a color. The middle of a color map shouldn't be black, because then the colors leading to the center would be darker, and the max and min values would be lighter, which is counter-intuitive.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily counter-intuitive. See for example the thermal colormap in cmocean. However, the reason I ask for it now is that I want to distinguish nan-values (shown as background color, i.e. white) from center-values.

Comment: You can use seaborn's [`diverging_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.diverging_palette.html), e.g. `cmap = sns.diverging_palette(250, 15, s=75, l=40, n=9, center="dark", as_cmap=True)`

Comment: If you want to change the NaN color, you can: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_bad

Comment: And what specific problem do you have to create your own colormap in matplotlib? [It's easy](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormap-manipulation-py).

Comment: If you want to differentiate the NaN values, you should use the link that Jody Klymak provided in the comments. I still, however, firmly believe that you should keep the center color of the diverging colormap white.

Comment: Thank you JohanC, that was what I was looking for. If you change your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Mr. T, I prefer to use existing colormaps, as I believe there's a lot of thought behind a good, intuitive colormap.

Comment: @DapperDuck Black-centered diverging colormap very much have a purpose. For example, when plotting radial velocity maps. The further away a value is from the center, the higher its value and thus the brighter it should appear. You don't care about values that are close to the center, because they are low, thus they should appear dark.
CMasher provides several black-centered diverging colormaps exactly because of that.

Comment: @1313e I see, this is indeed a good application! My apologies for the incorrect assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohanC put an obvious answer in their comment and I didn't see it because of the accepted answer which requires a less-known package:

[Seaborn supports arbitrary diverging palettes with black center](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.diverging_palette.html)

```
hue_neg, hue_pos = 250, 15
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(hue_neg, hue_pos, center="dark", as_cmap=True)
```

[image: example above in jupyter]